# SOLR return a value in multiValue field

Tags: solr, solrj, multivalue

I'm newbie in SOLR and I have a problem with multi values field.

My document has the following format:

```
{
"question":[
   "question 1",
   "question 2".
   "question 3"
   "question 4"
],

"answer": "Here is the answer"
}
```

When I search for the query: "question:question 2", SOLR returns the hold document as:

```
{"question":[
   "question 1",
   "question 2".
   "question 3"
   "question 4"
],

"answer": "Here is the answer"}
```

Is there any way to make the result contains only the "best" value of multi-values field:

```
{
"question":[
   "question 2".
],

"answer": "Here is the answer"
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, Solr will return all the values in the field.

Comment: What is the goal for returning a single value?

Comment: For auto suggestion purpose, I just want to return the most relevant element, not all the hold list. It will be easy if question - answer is 1 - 1, but in my case, many questions may have same answer.

Comment: Index each question as a separate document instead of having them as a multivalued field. It makes everything easier.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Highlighting to catch the reason why a document was found.
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html

Answer (score 0):

Please share your schema file if following doesnt solve your problem.
Have the field type of `question` as

```html
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="SetOfTextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And fire the query as `question:"question 2"`